# Meta tags on Drupal blog home page

Tags: meta-tags, nodes

How can I overwrite meta tags on the Drupal blog homepage? I'm using a "Blog" module ( which creates a blog homepage with the URL www.mysite.org/blog ) and a "Metateg" module for generating and overwriting title, description and keywords meta tags. The problem is that I can't find a way to overwrite the default generated meta tags for the blog home page since Metatag module doesn't provide this functionality. Is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the metatag_context sub module of Metatag, which means you need the [Context](https://www.drupal.org/project/context) module.

I was thrown for a loop on this as well. It'll create a default Context for a few of these oddball situations. Your metatag information is then controlled through Context.

See source for export handling blog: http://cgit.drupalcode.org/metatag/tree/metatag_context/metatag_context.context.inc#n251